# `index` in OpenGPT API output

Tags: python, openai-api

The following is the code

```
import os
import openai


openai.api_key = "..."


response = openai.Completion.create(
  model="text-davinci-003",     
  prompt="I am happy!",
  temperature=0, #creativity
  max_tokens=10,
  top_p=1,
  frequency_penalty=0.0,
  presence_penalty=0.0,
  suffix='I am even more happy!'
)

print(response)
```

Following is the output

```
{
  "choices": [
    {
      "finish_reason": "length",
      "index": 0,
      "logprobs": null,
      "text": "\n\nI am happy because I am surrounded by"
    }
  ],
  "created": 1674640360,
  "id": "cmpl-6cWkK124234ho8C2134afasdasdnwDKLUMP",
  "model": "text-davinci-003",
  "object": "text_completion",
  "usage": {
    "completion_tokens": 10,
    "prompt_tokens": 10,
    "total_tokens": 20
  }
}
```

What does the `index` in above following output represent?

Comment: In their API documentation the requests are fairly well documents, the responses... not so much. https://beta.openai.com/docs/api-reference/completions

Answer (score 2):

The index refers to the index of the `prompt` the reply is for.

Since `prompt` can be an string or an array, the [documentation](https://beta.openai.com/docs/api-reference/completions/create) refers to it as:

> ##### prompt <sup>**string or array**</sup>
>
> The prompt(s) to generate completions for, **encoded as a string**, **array of strings**, array of tokens, or array of token arrays.

---

As example, consider calling the [`/completions`](https://beta.openai.com/docs/api-reference/completions/create#completions/create-prompt) endpoint with 2 `prompt`'s:

```
{
    "model": "text-davinci-003",
    "prompt": [ 
      "How should I",                            // [ 0 ]
      "Should I"                                 // [ 1 ] 
    ],
    "max_tokens": 7,
    "temperature": 0
}
```

OpenAI will answer to both those prompts, and the `index` will refer to what original index in the `prompt` the reply is for:

```json
{
    "choices": [
        {
            "text": " go about doing this?\n\n",
            "index": 0,                              // Answers prompt[0]
            "logprobs": null,
            "finish_reason": "length"
        },
        {
            "text": " use a VPN on my iPhone?",
            "index": 1,                              // Answers prompt[1]
            "logprobs": null,
            "finish_reason": "length"
        }
    ]
}
```

---

In your example, there is only 1 `prompt`, so the API will only send 1 object in the `choices` array, so the `index` will always be `0`.